# Session bug using facebook-connect-with-authlogic in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, facebook, authlogic, facebooker

I'm trying to follow this article: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/03/testing-facebook, but I'm stuck.  I think the problem is with my session, in that the `current_user`method comes up with nil for `session[:facebook_session]`.

According to the original authlogic, it says to use the active_record_store for sessions:

```
# config/environment.rb
config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store
# db/schema includes
  create_table "sessions", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "session_id", :null => false
    t.text     "data"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

The article calls for the use of cookies.  I'm confused; can I use cookies and the active record sessions?  I'm also confused by the use of `cattr_accessor :current_user` from within the User model -- `current_user` still goes in the application controller, right?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should be able to still use the cookies and sessions in harmony; Facebook sets & uses cookies (afaik) regardless of how your application's sessions are configured.

The `cattr_accessor :current_user` is used elsewhere in our application (for reasons I can't recall right now) and should really be left out of the post. Thanks for bringing it up! Yes, there should still be a `current_user` method in `ApplicationController`.

Apologies that it took so long to respond, you sent the Twitter message to me at 1am my time, I read it at 3am (due to somebody drumming next door) and I've been busy today up until now (4pm)! I sincerly hopes this helps and if you need more help I should be around for a while yet!

Comment: I'm confused why session[:facebook_session] keeps coming up nil.